# How to define resources for custom classes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

This is a follow up to the question [What is the correct way to define classes in Xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618114/what-is-the-correct-way-to-define-classes-in-xaml)

I've managed to get resources running, having fun now. But I realize I have to define the resource as part of a Window class this way, I've seen some samples and they seem to using either UserControl, Applicaion or Window to encapsulate the resources. This makes good sense since the resources are going to be used in the UI, but I wanna ask, is it possible to define resources as part of custom classes? If I have a Person class, can I define resources for it using XAML? using Person.Xaml and Person.Xaml.cs?

Comment: Just out of curiosity- why would you want to do this?  The xaml resources you define aren't really useful outside of the UI context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thats a bit tricky, if Person is just a class it wont have any corrisponding Xaml file.

One way would be to store your resources in your `App.Xaml` then you can access these from anywhere in your application.

Example:

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication13.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MyAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:5" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Person class

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        var storyboard = (Storyboard)Application.Current.Resources["MyAnimation"];
    }
}
```

Another way is to create your own `Resource.Dictionaries` and load them in.

Comment: how do i create my own Resource.Dictionaries, is it a .Xaml file too?

Comment: I suggest looking at this link as my answer would go beyond the limit of this comment :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Resource Dictionary (Add new item of type Resource Dictionary) and can have all your resources within this XAML file. It is a good practice to define your reusable resources within a resource dictionary and use it where ever you need